# get() function in Tkinter always returns 0

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to get the contents of an entry box and when i use the .get() function it always return 0 doesnt matter what i write in the box

```
window1 = Tk()
window1.geometry("500x720+750+0")
entry1 = IntVar()
e1 = tk.Entry(window1, width=8,fg="darkblue", textvariable=entry1, font=('secular one', 13)).place(x=20, y=60)
num_of_diners = entry1.get()


def get_value():
    tk.Label(window1, text=num_of_diners, font=('secular one', 20)).place(x=300, y=510)


tk.Button(window1, text="calculate price", command=get_value, font=('secular one', 18), relief=(FLAT)).place(x=20, y=500)

window1.mainloop()
```

thats the code simplified a bit but its whats giving me problem for example if i write 4 in the entry box and then press the button it shows 0

Comment: You called `.get()` *immediately after creating the Entry* - how could it possibly return any sort of useful value?  You have to do the `.get()` later, perhaps in the Button's `command=` function,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `get()` inside the `get_value()` function

*UPDATE* - I misread the code previously - this should work now.

FYI:

1. You don't need an `IntVar` to store the value of the `Entry`, you can just call `get()` directly and do away with setting the `textvariable` parameter
2. You should make a habit of declaring your widgets separately from adding them to a geometry manager (i.e. `pack`, `grid`, `place`). The geometry manager methods always return `None`, so something like `my_entry = tk.Entry(root).pack()` will always evaluate to `None`, which is probably not what you want

```
entry1 = tk.Entry(window1, width=8,fg="darkblue", font=('secular one', 13))
entry1.place(x=20, y=60)


def get_value():
    num_of_diners = int(entry1.get())  # get entry contents as an integer
    tk.Label(window1, text=num_of_diners, font=('secular one', 20)).place(x=300, y=510)
```

Bear in mind that if the contents of `entry1` can't be cast to an `int` you'll get an exception. An easy way around this is:

```
def get_value():
    entry_content = entry1.get()
    if entry_content.isdigit():
        num_of_diners = int(entry_content)
    else:
        num_of_diners = 0  # fall back to 0 on conversion failure
```

Comment: it gives me the same outcome

Comment: What are you expecting to see? I know you're expecting to see the contents of your `Entry`, so I guess what I'm asking is: what is the content in `e1` when you press the button?

Comment: @Roei Did you have more than one instance of `Tk()`?